# CORS issue working with DJango Simple SSO

Tags: django, cors, single-sign-on, cross-domain, django-cors-headers

I'm using a fork of [Django Simple SSO](https://github.com/naudit/django-simple-sso) as an authentication mechanism on a Server.
It works great while we use the "standard" way to log in on the server. This means, we just access to the /login path, log in, and then navigate across the restricted paths, etc.

The problem comes when we want to connect to a 3rd server that also relays on SSO auth vía javascript/AJAX without direct access to /login path first.

I've tried to use django-cors-headers but didn't get the expected result.
I'm close to give up so any help is welcome.

### The problem

Assume we are logged in on server 1 and auth server and we want a resource on server 2
[image]

When the browser is redirected to the Auth Server in order to verify that the browser is logged with a valid user, the `cookie` header is not transferred.
(See the diagram on button for further details on how Django Simple SSO works)

The headers set by the **auth-server** on the **preflight** request are the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept-encoding, accept, authorization, cookie, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-grafana-org-id, x-dashboard-id, x-panel-id, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://server1-domain
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 16 Jul 2021 12:14:54 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Origin
```

The headers on the GET request where the following:

**Request/Client**:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: auth-server-domain
Origin: https://server1-domain
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
x-grafana-org-id: 1
```

**Response/Auth Server**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://server1-domain
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: es
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 16 Jul 2021 12:14:54 GMT
Location: /error_unauthorized_page
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I think all the headers are correct, but it's clearly there are some error.
On the cookie side, I have tried to play with the `SingleSite` property, setting it to `None` and `Lax` without any change.
The domain set on the cookie browser's memory is "correct" from my point of view as it is `.auth-server-domain` (note the dot).

I'm using DJango 3.2.5 and Google Chrome as a web browser.
If you have any idea of why cookie is not being send on the auth-server-domain cors requests, I will really appreciate your comments.

If do you think I have missed any piece of relevant information, feel free to ask!
Thank everyone to reach this point and help me!

---

### Appendix:

A simplified schema of how Simple SSO works:
[image: Django Simple SSO workflow]